# Need to find complete text of an HTML paragraph

Tags: selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdQto.png)

I am trying to get text wrapped in paragraph , below this div node.

I tried using this - I am getting Null value

driver.findElement(By.id("popoverContent")).getText()

using this also give me null:

driver.findElement(By.id("popoverContent")).getAttribute("innerhtml")

Please help

Comment: Is the #popoverContent visible?
Can you try the second instruction with this casing too: getAttribute("innerHTML") ?

Comment: Thanks @remborg .. Casting HTML in uppercase worked.. Thanks buddy!